# app crashes when try to get text from clipboard (Android 12)

Tags: java, android, crash, clipboard

I want to get the primary text on my clipboard and would like to know how to do that in newer android versions.
This code works perfectly when I tested it in an emulator running Android Pie, but the app crashes when I use it on my Phone running android 12.1.
please help me with this.

```
clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())
                clipItem = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
            clipText = clipItem.getText().toString();
            Details.setText(clipItem.getText().toString());
```

Here's the Error I got from Logcat

```
2022-10-01 19:23:27.595  1349-5125  ClipboardService        pid-1349                             E  Denying clipboard access to com.jery.tachisyrpc, the application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
    2022-10-01 19:23:27.595  8222-8222  AndroidRuntime          com.jery.tachisyrpc                  D  Shutting down VM
    2022-10-01 19:23:27.596  8222-8222  AndroidRuntime          com.jery.tachisyrpc                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jery.tachisyrpc, PID: 8222
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jery.tachisyrpc/com.jery.tachisyrpc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.ClipData$Item.getText()' on a null object reference                                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111)                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)                                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                             at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.ClipData$Item.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.jery.tachisyrpc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Who put the info in the clipboard?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @blackapps The user puts the info in the clipboard and I'm aware that the app crashes due to _clipItem_ being null. I want to know if there's any way to get the primary text in clipboard on android 10+

Comment: Of course the user is involved. But is the user doing that with your aop?

Comment: No, the user puts text in clipboard from another app. I want to be able to get the text and display it in a Toast when the user opens my app after that.

Comment: First try to put some text in clipboard with your own app.